# can't use animate scrollTop with jscrollpane?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, scrolltop

I'm using the following jQuery function to smoothly scroll to page sections:

```
function scrollTo(element) {    
    //$('html, body').animate({           // before the addition of jscrollpane
    $('#full-page-container').animate({   // after addition of jscrollpane
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    }, 1500);
}
```

I've added [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html) to replace the default page scrollbar, and it seems that the *animate* function with *scrollTop* above won't work with jscrollpane, but works flawlessly without it.

Is it possible to use both jscrollpane and *animate* with *scrollTop* ?

Comment: Did you not get a good enough answer, Deca?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't use scrollTop.

However, scrollpane has their own built in scrolling, which you can see examples of [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to.html).

[Scroll To - JScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to.html)

Example, taken from the jScrollPane site:

```
var api = pane.data('jsp');

    $('#but-scroll-to').bind(
        'click',
        function()
        {
            // Note, there is also scrollToX and scrollToY methods if you only
            // want to scroll in one dimension
            api.scrollTo(parseInt($('#toX').val()), parseInt($('#toY').val()));
            return false;
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

**Notes:** You can't animate() and jScrollPane together. However, jScrollPane is nice enough to include this feature.  It isn't very intuitive, but I made a some examples for you.  Cheerio!

*See the [jScrollPane API](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) for more useful information.*

---

I had some examples, but jsfiddle is hanging on them (I can't even see the source code), so I have removed them.